# Highcharts barchart - legend is only hiding first and last series, others stay visible on X-axis

Tags: highcharts

I'm creating a bar chart where it should be possible to hide each bar via legend.

However, only first and last series are getting fully hidden. The ones in the middle disappear from the plot area, but their labels remain visible at the X axis.

Here's a sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ananasij/wzk3dvnr/19/). Click through the legend starting from the first/last item and from the middle ones and you'll see what I'm talking about.

And here are the chart options I'm passing through:

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Compare scores per department'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            grouping: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            },
    },
    series: [
        { name: 'department 1', data: [{ name: 'department 1', y: 45 }] },
        { name: 'department 2', data: [{ name: 'department 2', y: 68 }] },
        { name: 'department 3', data: [{ name: 'department 3', y: 82 }] },
        { name: 'department 4', data: [{ name: 'department 4', y: 37 }] }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas of how to fix it or alternative ways to implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared to be a known issue with category axes (hidden points are only hiding first/last categories).

I got the following workaround from Highcahrts team:
using `series.events.legendItemClick` event for setting empty data to the item on hide and then putting data back when it's shown again:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function () {
                if (this.visible) {
                    this.setData([], false)
                } else {
                    this.setData([seriesArray[this.index]], false);
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e942js4/3/)

I hope it will help someone who is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need also categories on xAxis (which in bars is vertical on the left) but it's enough the legend, you can change options this way:

```
xAxis: {
   labels: {
     enabled: false
   }
},
plotOptions: {
   // any
}
```

Check the fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/zbktpf0g/

**UPDATE:**

in addition, as suggested by [Deep 3015](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3898339/deep-3015) you can enable [dataLabels](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.dataLabels):

```
plotOptions : {
    series : {
        dataLabels : {
            enabled : true,
            align : 'left',
            color : '#FFFFFF',
            inside : true,
            formatter : function () {
                return this.key
            }
        },
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I do need them though, since it's a part of the  requirements. So, getting rid of them is not an option for me, unfortunately...

Comment: @Deep3015  That won't work for me neither, since I have to display series values as outside labels. Sorry, I should have included that in the fiddle as well (updated now).